# Sorting Values in Google Sheet using loop in Google Apps Script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am trying to create a function in Google Sheets using Google Apps Script.

I have a list of 300 values in Sheet 1, Column A.

I have a formula which needs to be applied on each value (in Column A), one by one.

The output of the formula should be "Select" or "Reject".

I am able to do it manually, but I need it to be automated using Google Apps Script.

I have numbers in Column A and I want to find their square root in Cell B2, row by row. When the square root is greater than a defined value, the original number should get listed in column C, while numbers without a square root greater than the defined value should be listed in column D (See example below).

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This process will take 5 steps; a loop, if/else statements, JavaScript arithmetic, comparative operators, and finally writing data back to the sheet. For your row values, it is assumed that you have a header row (frozen or otherwise) that shouldn't be used in calculations.

You can find a great guide on JavaScript operators, arithmetic and general language here:

http://www.w3schools.com/js/default.asp

Step 1: Looping & General Variable Definition

```
function myFunction() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getActiveSheet();
  var range = sheet.getActiveRange();
  var lastRow = sheet.getLastRow();
  var checkColumn = sheet.getMaxColumns();
  var checkRange = sheet.getRange(2, checkColumn, (lastRow - 1), 1);
  var check = checkRange.getValues();
  var red = "#ff0404";
  var green = "#3bec3b";
```

You'll notice that the `.getRange` method uses numbered rows and columns to define a start place and then an **index** to define how many rows/ columns to include. `.lastRow` gives a numerical value to which we need to subtract 1 for the index value.

I also use a technique for looping that includes showing which cells have already been processed. This allows for the line-by-line structure you want while also pinpointing where an error may have occurred.

```
  for (var i = 0; i < check.length; i++) {
```

This is the basic structure for a loop. We have an index, i, that we increment after each time through the loop. The most common index is 'i' but other variables can be used. It is also good practice to change the name of your indexes should you loop within a loop.

Step 2: If/Else Statements

```
    if (check[i] == "✓") {
          continue;
        } else {
         var checkCell = sheet.getRange((i+2), checkColumn, 1, 1);
         function sorter() {
           var number = sheet.getRange((i+2), 1, 1, 1).getValue();
           var sqrtCell = sheet.getRange((i+2), 2, 1, 1);
           var moreCell = sheet.getRange((i+2), 3, 1, 1);
           var lessCell = sheet.getRange((i+2), 4, 1, 1);
           var outputCell = sheet.getRange((i+2), 5, 1, 1);
```

We set a condition to check, `if (check[i] == "✓") {`, and a action to take, `continue,`. This basically means that if we have already set a marker that the row has been processed, skip over it and check the next one. `check[i]` uses our index we set to loop through all of the values to look for '✓'.

After that we set an alternative if the statement was false. This is where the meat of the code comes in and processes the numbers and writes the data. The `.getRange` methods are all to define exactly where to look and where to write.

Step 3: Arithmetic

```
           var squareRoot = Math.sqrt(number);
           sqrtCell.setValue(squareRoot);
```

These are JavaScript methods that will not be shown in the GAS Reference as they are integral to JavaScript itself. You can refer to w3schools to find more. At this point we have found the square root programatically and written the value back to the cell defined earlier.

Step 4 & 5: Operators & Writing Values

```
    if (squareRoot >= 10) {
      moreCell.setValue(number);
      outputCell.setValue("Select");
      outputCell.setBackground(green);
    } else {
      lessCell.setValue(number);
      outputCell.setValue("Reject");
      outputCell.setBackground(red);
    }
```

Here is another if/else statement that uses an operator for the condition. We check our sqrt variable this time and use the operator `>=` for greater-than-or-equal-to. If we find that the statement is true, write the original number to one column, label another column as "Select" and make that label green. If we find that the statement is false, write the original number to a different column, label "Reject", and make the label red.

We finish out the code by telling it to first make the check cell red, then crunch the numbers, then reset the background and write our denotation mark.

```
    }
      checkCell.setBackground(red);
      sorter();
      checkCell.setBackground('white');
      checkCell.setValue("✓");
    }
  }
}
```

You can make your mark anything you prefer and can use varying CSS color formats to easily label cells as you choose. The order in which you tell your code to perform is crucial. Take care to test frequently and make sure that things are happening when and how you tell them to.

You will notice that we define what the `sorter()` function is first and then call it in order after. This makes sure that it actually runs right when we need it to.

I would also suggest looking into `onEdit()` and time-triggers so that it will run automatically when there is an edit made/ value added or at set time intervals.

The full code and reference pictures have been included below.

```
function myFunction() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getActiveSheet();
  var range = sheet.getActiveRange();
  var lastRow = sheet.getLastRow();
  var checkColumn = sheet.getMaxColumns();
  var checkRange = sheet.getRange(2, checkColumn, (lastRow - 1), 1);
  var check = checkRange.getValues();
  var red = "#ff0404";
  var green = "#3bec3b";
  for (var i = 0; i < check.length; i++) {
    if (check[i] == "✓") {
      continue;
    } else {
      var checkCell = sheet.getRange((i+2), checkColumn, 1, 1);
      function sorter() {
        var number = sheet.getRange((i+2), 1, 1, 1).getValue();
        var sqrtCell = sheet.getRange((i+2), 2, 1, 1);
        var moreCell = sheet.getRange((i+2), 3, 1, 1);
        var lessCell = sheet.getRange((i+2), 4, 1, 1);
        var outputCell = sheet.getRange((i+2), 5, 1, 1);
        var squareRoot = Math.sqrt(number);
        sqrtCell.setValue(squareRoot);
        if (squareRoot >= 10) {
          moreCell.setValue(number);
          outputCell.setValue("Select");
          outputCell.setBackground(green);
        } else {
          lessCell.setValue(number);
          outputCell.setValue("Reject");
          outputCell.setBackground(red);
        }
      }
      checkCell.setBackground(red);
      sorter();
      checkCell.setBackground('white');
      checkCell.setValue("✓");
    }
  }
}
```

[image: Blank Sheet with Values & Headers]

[image: While the code is running]

[image: After is has finished]

Comment: Thanks Christopher ... instead of sqrt Can I use Googlefinance() method to pull data and populate in the sheet and then apply some formula on the data populated by go0gle finance .... this is my actual requirement    here is link of my sample sheet  https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1pCzdZjajoRa0hIZSNzz6uj87rtzOu4QGi1p7LZalS8k/edit?usp=sharing  I wish that all the symbols on sheet1 should get pulled one by one and on sheet2 their data is populated and the formula which i have used gets applied to data

Comment: I'm not familiar with `GOOGLEFINANCE()` but I have used several sheet functions within my automated systems. My functions sometimes work independently but more frequently are linked and have chained dependency.
In general, it is best practice to separate the cells you will read from the ones that you will write to. So you can read any data that `GOOGLEFINANCE()` writes with the code but make sure that you have blank (functionless) cells/ columns for where you need to write data.

Comment: Also, why is it that you need 2 sheets? It would more simply view-able from one sheet and all of your formulas would work the same way.

When applying the code, ensure that your ranges are set appropriately as well.

Comment: Please select an answer as accepted if it has solved your issue.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Google Query and avoid scripting if you want.

`=QUERY(A2:A,"select A where A <=55",0)`

That should return values less than or equal to 55 from column A. You'd duplicate that in the next column and change it to >. There's working example [here](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1ggmoFJRDDb9RqpVCkHM1HectYItxLzCRULO8UWwMsoo/edit#gid=0).

As a heads up, I don't think you're getting the square root in the B column based on that screenshot. I think the square root of 34 should be ~ 5.8 rather than the 7.48 your sheet is showing. You can calculate that with as well with `=SQRT(A2)`

Comment: Thanks Tom for help... But this is not what i want to do i just gave an example and more over the formula which i am going to use is complex one that formula in turn is going to fetch some more data